# How to bind a buffer in lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to draw a triangle in the middle of the screen using lwjgl and OpenGL. My current code looks like this:

```
int vertexBuffer = glCreateBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                              //and initalised FloatBuffer
```

And the main loop:

```
while (glfwWindowShouldClose(windowID) == GL_FALSE) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(windowID);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the `glCreateBuffers()` function. Instead of binding the buffer itself to OpenGL, you generate an ID:

```
IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
glCreateBuffers(buffer);
int id = buffer.get(0);
```

You could also just call `glCreateBuffers()` without arguments and use the return value as ID:

```
int id = glCreateBuffers();
```

To write data to this buffer you first have to bind it, this just tells OpenGL that you want to write to the bound offer.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
```

As you can see you pass in the generated ID, to bind the corresponding buffer.

Next you can write to the OpenGL buffer, like this:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

This sends the contents of `g_vertex_buffer_data` to the OpenGL context on the GPU. `g_vertex_buffer_data` contains your vertex data (model data) and you do not want to create a buffer OF this java.nio.Buffer, but let OpenGL generate an ID for a GPU-buffer and then send the contents of your java.nio.Buffer to the GPU-buffer.

For information look at the [LWJGL Wikipage](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/index.php?title=Using_Vertex_Buffer_Objects_%28VBO%29) about Vertex Buffer.

Comment: thanks man, this works now, but it still doesn't draw anything although the g_vertex_buffer_data is correct and the glDrawArrays() is called. Any additional suggestions?

Comment: Well, I found out that there was a glfwWindowHint call which set the OpenGL-Version to 3.3 which was the reason it didn't draw anything. But still, thanks for help